# The probability of a stolen car will be recovered is $0.5$. Find the probability that atleast one out of $20$ cars stolen is recovered?

Tags: probability

Solution:- 
probability of a car recovered is $0.5$,
the probability that it wont be recovered is $1-0.5= 0.5$
To find:- atleast one car is recovered, $r=1$, $n=20$.
Probability that a car would be recovered is:- $1$-(probability that none will be recovered)
$= 1-$${20}\choose{0}$$(0.5)^{20}
=0.99.$

Is the solution right?

Comment: $0.999999046$ might be closer.  But you have to make a strong independence assumption. If there were a $0.5$ chance all the cars would be recovered and a $0.5$ chance they would all not be then the result would be $0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean $$1-\binom{20}0(0.5)^{20}=1-(0.5)^{20}\;,$$ your method is fine, but this is actually about $0.999999$, not $0.99$. If you were rounding to two decimal places, the answer would be $1.00$.